# Classical limit of a quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential

If we have a one dimensional system where the potential

$$V~=~\begin{cases}\infty & |x|\geq d, \\ a\delta(x) &|x|<d, \end{cases}$$

where $a,d >0$ are positive constants, what then is the corresponding classical case -- the approximate classical case when the quantum number is large/energy is high?

Comment: What is $V$ when $x \in (-d,0) \cup (0,d)$?

Comment: @KarsusRen: 0 -- it is the "otherwise" case.

Comment: Did you mean "$\infty$ when $|x| > d$"? Also did you mean "$a$ when $x = 0$" i.e. $a\delta(x)$. Finally is $a$ of the order of classical energies or much less? If the latter, the system just looks like a square well with no barrier at classical energies.

Comment: @JohnRennie: Thank you for pointing out my mistakes! I have edited the question accordingly. I only know that $a>0$. Also, I never realised that the delta function there means a when x=0, since the delta function is supposedly infinite -- got me rather confused.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it (I hope) clearer. If this isn't what you meant please roll back my edit.

Comment: Dear @Sys, it's a virtue and necessity, not a bug, that the delta-function is infinite at $x=0$. If it were finite at a single point (i.e. interval of length zero), like in your example, it would have no impact on the particle because zero times finite is zero. So your potential as you wrote it is physically identical to $V=\infty$ for $|x|<d$ and $0$ otherwise which is just a well with the standing wave energy eigenstates. The finite modification of $V$ at one point, by $a$, plays no role at all. A potential with $a\delta(x)$ in it would be another problem.

Comment: @LubošMotl: Thanks, actually the delta function version instead of V=a at x=0 is the right one. What is the classical limit of that?

Comment: @JohnRennie: I think your comment suggestion was right, that there is a delta function at x=0.

Comment: Dear @Sys, you may also look at the classical trajectories. The force or acceleration is equal to $a \delta'(x)$ here. So the velocity will get a bump proportional to $a\delta$ and the position will get a step function. So I guess that classically, such a potential will make the particle jump by a fixed distance once it reaches the point. Good that such a thing doesn't occur in classical physics. I still think that for a fixed $a$ and a classical limit of a high kinetic energy, the jump will be very short again. It's plausible that for a finite $a$, the jump in $x$ will be just $\sim\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we derive the bound state spectrum from scratch. Not surprisingly, the conclusion is that the Dirac delta potential doesn't matter in the semi-classical continuum limit, in accordance with Spot's answer.

The time-independent Schrödinger equation reads for positive $E>0$,

$$ -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\psi^{\prime\prime}(x) ~=~ (E-V(x))\psi(x), \qquad V(x)~:=~V_0\delta(x)+\infty \theta(|x|-d), \qquad V_0~>~0, $$

with the convention that $0\cdot \infty=0$.
Define

$$v(x) ~:=~ \frac{2mV(x)}{\hbar^2}, \qquad e~:=~\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}~>~0 \qquad k~:=~\sqrt{e}~>~0\qquad 
v_0 ~:=~ \frac{2mV_0}{\hbar^2}. $$

Then

$$ \psi^{\prime\prime}(x) ~=~ (v(x)-e)\psi(x). $$

We know that the wave function $\psi$ is continuous with boundary conditions

$$\psi(x)~=0 \qquad  {\rm for}\qquad  |x|\geq d.$$

Also the derivative $\psi^{\prime}$ is continuous for $0<|x|<d$, and possibly has a kink at $x=0$,

$${\lim}_{\epsilon\to 0^+}[\psi^{\prime}(x)]^{x=\epsilon}_{x=-\epsilon} ~=~v_0\psi(x=0). $$

We get $$\psi_{\pm}(x)~=~A_{\pm}\sin(k(x\mp d))\qquad {\rm for } \qquad 
0 \leq \pm x \leq d.$$

1. $\underline{\text{Case} ~\psi(x=0)=0}$. Then 
   $$n~:=~\frac{kd}{\pi}~\in~ \mathbb{N}.$$ 
   We get an odd wave function 
   $$\psi_n(x)~\propto~\sin(kx).$$
   In particularly, the odd wave functions do not feel the presence of the Dirac delta potential.
2. $\underline{\text{Case} ~\psi(x=0)\neq 0}$. Then continuity at $x=0$ implies that the wave function is even $A_{+}+A_{-}=0$. Phrased equivalently,
   $$\psi(x)~=~A\sin(k(|x|-d)).$$
   The kink condition at $x=0$ becomes
   $$ v_0A\sin(-kd)~=~2kA \cos(kd), $$
   or equivalently,
   $$ v_0\tan(kd)~=~-2k.$$
   In the semiclassical continuum limit 
   $$k \gg \frac{1}{d}, \qquad k \gg v_0,$$ 
   this becomes 
   $$\frac{kd}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}~\in ~\mathbb{Z}, $$
   i.e., in the semiclassical continuum limit the even wave functions do not feel the presence of the Dirac delta potential as well.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's easy to start off with just the Dirac delta potential and see what that does. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential) has a nice solution for the Delta fuction potential, and I am lifting off parts of it here.

Consider a potential $V(x) = a\delta (x)$ and consider a scattering like configuration, where a plane wave $e^{ikx}$ is incident from the left.

$$
\psi(x)=\begin{cases}e^{ikx}+re^{-ikx} & x<0 \\ te^{ikx} & x> 0\end{cases}
$$

By matching the boundary conditions, like on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_potential) page, you get
$$
t = 1+r\\
(1-\alpha)t = 1-r
$$

where
$$
\alpha = \frac{ 2ma}{ik\hbar^2}
$$
characterizes the effect of the delta potential. Solving for $r$ and $t$, 
$$
t = \frac{1}{1-\alpha/2}\\
r=-\frac{\alpha/2}{1-\alpha/2}
$$

Now, it is easy to see that for high incident $k$, the only effect of the dirac delta potential is to write a phase discontinuity on the wavefuction. This is because, as $k$ increases, the transmission $|t|^2=1/(1+|\alpha|^2/4)$ approaches 1, but the transmitted wavefunction gets an extra phase given by 
$$
\text{Arg}(t) = -\tan^{-1}(|\alpha|/2)
$$

Getting back to the problem at hand, for a particle in a box (without the delta function), the allowed $k$ vectors are given by forcing the wavefunction to be zero at the walls at $x=-d$ and $x=d$, which gives us the condition

$$
k_n=\frac{\pi n}{2d}
$$

If now, we add a delta potential, then for high values of $n$ (or $k$), all the delta function will do is introduce a phase discontinuity at the origin, and consequently what you should expect is that the boundary condition is matched not for $k_n$, but something slightly off $k_n+\delta k_n$, where $\delta k_n$ is a small correction due to the delta function potential. For high values of $n$, this correction would drop, as the phase discontinuity decreases, and for classical like states (very large $n$) you expect to recover 1D box states, as mentioned by John Rennie.